# MYSQL subqueries using LIKE and IN

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I'm trying to put together a MYSQL query designed for an AJAX\PHP CMS, which goes a little like this:

```
SELECT table.info 
FROM table 
WHERE table.variable LIKE '%refinedby%' IN 
(SELECT other valid subquery to select data from)
```

However, I keep tripping syntax errors near LIKE '%refinedby'IN (

If I use = rather than LIKE there's no problem, as the following:

```
SELECT table.info 
FROM table 
WHERE table.variable = 'refinedby' IN 
(SELECT other valid subquery to select data from)
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I can't preceed a subquery with a LIKE selector?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use in like that you have to specify what is going to BE in

```
SELECT table.info 
FROM table 
WHERE table.variable LIKE '%refinedby%' 
and table.variable IN (SELECT other valid subquery to select data from)
```